# Why the head of linked list in java is not getting changed (although objects in Java are passed as reference)?

Tags: java

The following code is supposed to increment the head pointer to the next node in linked list. However, it doesn't do so. But the value of head data is being changed.

The `changeHead(Node head)` method is changing the head of the linked list as the next node of the linked list.

Could anybody please help me out why only data value is getting changed but head pointer of the linked list is not getting changed ?

```
class Node
{
int data;
Node next;
Node(int data)
  {
   this.data=data;
   this.next=null;
  }
}

class LinkedList
{
 Node head;

 public LinkedList() //constructor for LinkedList class
 {
  this.head=null;  
 }

 void insert(int data)
 {
  Node s=new Node(data);
  if(head==null)
  {
    head=s;
  }
  else
  {
   Node t=head;
   while(t.next!=null)
       t=t.next;
   t.next=s;
  }
}
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       LinkedList ll=new LinkedList();
       ll.insert(1);
       ll.insert(2);
       ll.insert(3);
       ll.insert(4);
       printList(ll.head); //calling method to print the list
       changeHead(ll.head); //changing the head to the next node
       printList(ll.head); //calling method to print the changed list

    }
   static void printList(Node head)
    {
       Node t=head;
       while(t!=null)
       {
            System.out.print(t.data+" ");
            t=t.next;
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
     static void changeHead(Node head) 
     {
      head=head.next;
     }

  }


Output:
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4

Expected output:
1 2 3 4
2 3 4

/*However if I change the function changeHead(Node head) as */
static void changeHead(Node head)
 {
  head.data=444;
 }  
then the output is as per expectations i.e. 
1 2 3 4
444 2 3 4
```

Comment: Objects in Java aren't passed by reference. References are passed by value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1

Comment: As an aside, for further questions, your code would be easier to read if you'd apply consistent indentation to everything. On the other hand, thanks for including a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Since the reference `head` is passed in by value and you change that value (you change where the reference points to) the caller does not see any change.

If you use the reference of `head` to change some of the contents `head` points to then that change is visible to everyone.

Comment: Could you please help me with the required code in Java to make the next node as head ?